# C# Regex to match UTC dates

Tags: c#, datetime, regex

Made the following regex strings to match for typical UTC dates. I'd appreciate it if you guys can let me know if it seems fine and not too lengthy.

```
[1-2](0|9)\d{2}(?([0-0])0\d{1}|1[0-2])[0-3]\d{1} // yyyyMMdd
[1-2](0|9)\d{2}-(?([0-0])0\d{1}|1[0-2])-[0-3]\d{1} // yyyy-MM-dd
\d{2}(?([0-0])0\d{1}|1[0-2])[0-3]\d{1} // yyMMdd
\d{2}-(?([0-0])0\d{1}|1[0-2])-[0-3]\d{1} // yy-MM-dd
(\p{Ll}|\p{Lu}){3,9}[0-3]\d{1}[1-2](0|9)\d{2} // MMMddyyyy or MMMMddyyyy
```

Comment: Why are you trying to parse dates with a regex?  It might be more useful to use something like [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22(v=vs.110).aspx), using the overload that takes in a list of possible formats.

Comment: Oh I see, so it would essentially work the same? Thanks

Comment: One purpose is to search/extract  dates from text.   I did this for a document management application.

Comment: @DanLyons yes it doesn't work with complicated strings. For instance, "IMGWA001q19940811-2436". TryParse and TryParseExact cannot extract the date 19940811